# My Scope Filter doesn't works, I'm getting the result of getting a select * from, instead of filtering

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm working on a small project using **Laravel** and **Vuejs**. I try to do a simple filter of ages

I send and I receive correctly my GET parameters (I've double-checked), I get the same result since I send different values.

it seems like my `scopeWithFilters` function doesn't work because I used the function `toSql` to see the query and the result was  `select * from users`  which means my scope function doesn't work.

This is my scope function :

```
public function scopeWithFilters($query, $minAge=Null, $maxAge=Null){
    $query->when(is_int($minAge), function($query) use ($minAge){
        $query->where('birthday_year', '<=', date('Y') - $minAge);
    
    })->when(is_int($maxAge), function($query) use ($maxAge){
        $query->where('birthday_year', '>=', date('Y') - $maxAge);
    
    });

    return $query;
}
```

This is my controller function :

```
public function filter(Request $request){

        $query = User::WithFilters(
            $request->input('minAge'),
            $request->input('maxAge')
        )->get();

        return UserResource::collection($query);
    }
```

after doing **->toSql()** to see the query:

```
select * from users
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is case sensitive, so instead of `User::WithFilters(` try `User::withFilters(`. Check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#utilizing-a-local-scope).

Also, you can have a "cleaner code" if you update your filters to this:

```php
public function scopeWithFilters($query, int $minAge=null, int $maxAge=null){
    return $query->when($minAge, function($query) use ($minAge) {
        $query->where('birthday_year', '<=', date('Y') - $minAge);
    })
    ->when($maxAge, function($query) use ($maxAge) {
        $query->where('birthday_year', '>=', date('Y') - $maxAge);
    });
}
```

---

If you are using PHP 8+, we could reduce your code to this (have in mind it is visual in this case, but maybe it is more readable for you too):

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder; // Add this on top with your other USEs

public function scopeWithFilters(Builder $query, int $minAge = null, int $maxAge = null)
{
    return $query->when(
        $minAge,
        fn(Builder $query) => $query->where('birthday_year', '<=', date('Y') - $minAge)
    )
    ->when(
        $maxAge,
        fn(Builder $query) => $query->where('birthday_year', '>=', date('Y') - $maxAge)
    );
}
```